# Performance issue in c#

Tags: c#

I am working on a c# project and I want to know the code snippet which is good out of the two below.

In first code snippet I am adding vehicleType inside modelmapper method. Its a call to service I want avoid that.

```
List<VehicleModel> vehiclesModel;
```

**First option**

```
vehiclesModel.Add(VehicleEntityToModelMapper(item, vehicleId, maxRecord, pageIndex));
```

**Second option**

```
VehicleModel vehicleModel = VehicleEntityToModelMapper(item, entityId, maxRecord, pageIndex);
vehicleModel.vehicleType = vehicleType;
vehiclesModel.Add(vehicleModel);
```

Which one is good considering the performance?

Comment: Version 2 is slightly slower because it additionally sets the vehicleType.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review and would be a better fit for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: `vehicleModel.vehicleType = vehicleType ;` where are you doing this in the first code? The question is not clear, I suppose.

Comment: Just a little note on your variable names: You shouldn't declare variables that differ only in a letter, which moreover lies in the middle of the word. The difference is easy to miss and makes the reading and understanding of your code a lot harder.

Comment: @ Shadow vehicleModel.vehicleType = vehicleType ; I am doing this inside mapper method in first version. Its a call to service so I want avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of what you are trying to achieve with your code the only **valid** way of choosing more efficient code is **benchmarking** results. Simply run your code on environment that is similar (ideally the same) to the production env and check the results. For more information about things to avoid check this [post by Eric Lippert](http://tech.pro/blog/1293/c-performance-benchmark-mistakes-part-one)

For your piece of code it looks like it shouldn't matter as you're doing effectively the same operations  and you only change how code looks in the editor.